# Google Cloud Memcache equivalent on IBM Bluemix

Tags: caching, ibm-cloud, memcached, ibm-mobile-services, ibm-cloud-plugin

I'm developing a webservice on IBM Bluemix with Liberty for Java and Cloudant and I have to cache some data in memory.

The auto-scaling component creates new instances of my application and I would a shared cache between instances.

Is there a sort of Memcache in IBM Bluemix like in Google Cloud?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at Redis:
https://console.bluemix.net/catalog/services/databases-for-redis or https://console.bluemix.net/catalog/services/compose-for-redis ? That should sort out your inmemory store needs.

Comment: Can you accept the answer if it did answer your question?